# Solving Polynomial in $\sin$ and $\cos$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

Given the following equation:

$$A \sin(t) + B\cos(t) =C\sin(t)\cos(t).$$

Can we solve the above equation without the need of using general solution of 4-order polynomial equation. We can use computer but not using the search algorithm.

Please help me, this problem can from the minimization of the following function:
$$f(t) = (A + R_1\cos{t})^2 + (B+ R_2\sin{t})^2.$$
that is the problem of finding minimum distance from the origin of coordinate to a ellipse.

in which, $A$, $B$,$C$, $R_1$, $R_2$ is constant. $t$ is variable.

thank you so much.

Comment: Try plugging in three different values of $t$ between $0$ and $\pi/2$ and solving the simultaneous equations.

Comment: Do you mean to solve for $t$ in terms of $A,$ $B,$ and $C$?

Comment: Yes, But we can use a intermediate variable similar to solve :
Asin(t) + Bcos(t) =C, with intermediate u = atan(a/b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the equation $$A \sin(t) + B\cos(t) -C\sin(t)\cos(t)=0$$ for which we should use tangent half-angle substitution $\big(x=\tan(\frac t2)\big)$. So, after simplifications, we get $$B x^4-2  (A+C)x^3- 2(A- C)x-B=0$$ which is your quartic.

For solving it, I should use Newton method which, starting from a guess $x_0$ will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ Strating with $x_0=0$, the first iterate is $$x_1=\frac{B}{2 (C- A)}$$

I do not think that you could obtain an explicit solution for the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your helps. I read from an article that they could get the exact solution. Anyway, they provided a solution with typos. I have ended up with optimized solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same problem: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2939540/

So far I've gotten to the below equation. Here, $z_0$ is a complex number who's real and imaginary parts are functions of the semi- major and minor axes of the ellipse and the xy coordinates of the interior point. I'm not sure how to proceed further without numerical methods, but I'd think the symmetry would yield a closed form solution.

$$z^4+2z_0z^3-2\bar{z_0}z-1=0$$